# Converting a nested dict to nested XML for DHTML TreeGrid Control

Tags: python, dhtmlx

I have a nested python dictionary that looks like the below, and I need to support any arbitrary levels of nesting.

```
{
'2012-08-07': {'17': ['30']}, 
'2012-08-24': {'3': ['70']}
}
```

But I need to convert to an xml format that looks like this:

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
        <rows id="start">
            <row id="1">
                <cell> 2012-08-07 </cell>
                <cell></cell>
                <row id="2">
                    <cell> 17 </cell>
                    <cell>30</cell>
                </row>
            </row>
              <row id="3">
                <cell> 2012-08-24 </cell>
                <cell></cell>
                <row id="4">
                    <cell> 3 </cell>
                    <cell>70</cell>
                </row>
            </row> 
        </rows>"""
```

This is for creating XML for the treegrid control using DHTMLX. The keys of the dict will be used for for the tree levels while the leaf list are the values.

Here is that actual dict I am using generated by defaultdict:

```
defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x30768e8>, {'2012-08-07': defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x3076890>, {'17': ['30']}), '2012-08-24': defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x3076890>, {'3': ['70']})})
```

Comment: Is there more to that dictionary?  It's incomplete in its current form.

Comment: I edited the dict. That is the proper form.  At the bottom, the real output is printed but cleaned it up becuase the dict was generated by default dict.